# need regex command to extract full filename which has 2 dot(.)

Tags: regex

i am having issue in extracting full filename which has  2 dot(.).
although below command is working but i need a alternate solution without asterix in regex.  can anyone help me out in alternate regex command to extract full filename without asterix?

```js
(ABC_A.*\.)+.*
```

Here are filenames I am trying to match:

```
ABC_A_CommunityRollover_Autocreate_Community.12345678-1.out
ABC_A_CommunityRollover_Autocreate_Community.88345678-1.out
ABC_A_CommunityRollover_Autocreate_Community.99945678-1.out
```

Comment: Try `^ABC_A([^.]+\.){2}[^.]+$`

Comment: Or you could also match the format of the string `^ABC_A\w+\.\d+-\d+\.\w+$` https://regex101.com/r/wb1DI0/1

Comment: Please explain what you are after. Matching only when a string contains two dots (and no more than two)? Does `^ABC_A[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$` [work well](https://regex101.com/r/wb1DI0/2) enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

```
^ABC_A(?:[^.]+\.){2}[^.]+$
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uVnmPB/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ABC_A                    'ABC_A'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]+                    any character except: '.' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^.]+                    any character except: '.' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```